# Need help in Oracle cast varchar array query

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, casting, union

I am looking for a query similar to the below one.

```
SELECT  ROWNUM rnum,COLUMN_VALUE as dl
FROM    TABLE(CAST(varc('REGULAR','AD','PR') is varray(3) of varchar2(100)))
```

Output :

```
REGULAR 
AD
PR
```

PS: Type creation is not allowed in our oracle 11g by DBA. 
Using union is one option. But we are looking for list of array elements in the select query

Any suggestions please!

Comment: I know there is little point in arguing with a DBA but, for the record, their prohibition is uninformed, misguided and counter-productive. Feel free to quote me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some [handy collection types already supplied by Oracle](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/handy-pre-defined-oracle-collections.html) - for example you could do:

```
select column_value
from table(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL('REGULAR','AD','PR'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It solves my problem ☺️

Comment: You should probably add a [disclosure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254283/1509264) to your answer that the link goes to your own blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` type:

```
SELECT ROWNUM,
       COLUMN_VALUE
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'REGULAR', 'AD', 'PR' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply